# MS-access append query for specific column

Tags: ms-access-2016

how can I use access append query for specific column for empty existing table contain same column and many other column include calculated columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Attached are images showing how to use append query to insert records from one table into another, including a calculated column.

The sample uses TableA(Table with existing records) and TableB table with no records, but similar columns has TableA.

[image: TableA]

[image: TableB with no record]

[image: Append Query design view]

[image: TableB with inserted records after running append query]